# SQLiteの.helpの？〜？の囲みについて

Tags: sqlite

初歩的な質問ですが、SQLiteの.helpを打った際に【画像】のようにSQLiteのタグ（？）がクェスチョンマークで囲まれているのは、これはどう言った意味でしょうか。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows の環境変数を `%環境変数%` の形で参照するのと同じく、`?...?` の部分は **任意の変数や値** に置き換える、だと思います。(`.dbconfig` の場合、`?op?` はオプション名)

**参考:**
[SQLite3 Command Line Shell dot-commands マニュアル(完全版) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kanegoon/items/fc1e4bfea0984dbe4b90#dbconfig-db%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)

> ```
> sqlite> .dbconfig
>           defensive off
>             dqs_ddl on
>             dqs_dml on
>         enable_fkey off
>         enable_qpsg off
>      enable_trigger on
>         enable_view on
>      fts3_tokenizer off
>  legacy_alter_table off
>  legacy_file_format off
>      load_extension on
>    no_ckpt_on_close off
>      reset_database off
>         trigger_eqp off
>      trusted_schema on
>     writable_schema on
> ```
>
> オプションを設定する場合、オプション名と値を引数として与えます。
>
> ```
> sqlite> .dbc load_extension off
>      load_extension off
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> .backup ?DB? FILE      Backup DB (default "main") to FILE
> ```

とあるので`??`は省略可能を表すのだと思います。この例では`?DB?`を省略すると`main`をバックアップする、と。対して`FILE`は省略不可。